# Limiting rows initially returned in select list

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Populating an Apex 5.1 select list of employees with about 25,000 names is proving to be a performance problem when loading the page. Is there a method of limiting the initial list to a set number (such as 200), and dynamically populating with chunks of additional names as the user scrolls through the list? Are there other options I should consider that would not slow down the page load?

I am currently using a dynamic LOV, and have tried adjusting this LOV to include Oracle row limiting code; however, there is no way of fetching past the initial set of rows. The source of the data is a view on a materialized view.

I appreciate any ideas

Comment: A select list doesn't seem like a particularly good control type to use for 25000 names.  Is a user really going to scroll through thousands of names?  A text field with autocomplete would seem like a much better approach.

Comment: Good idea - I'll explore that as an alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a pop-up LOV with a search function, not showing any records until the user enters a search value (more than 3 characters).  I know it's tedious to use a pop-up LOV but it seems the only way to prevent waiting for a slow list to display.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with cascading lists of values. I don't know what those 25.000 names represent, but - suppose it is a large company. Then you'd

- 1st LoV: continent
- 2nd Lov: country

  - which refers to the previous LoV as `where country.continent = :P1_CONTINENT`
- 3rd LoV: city

  - which refers the previous LoV as `where city.coutry = :P1_COUNTRY`
- 4rd Lov is actually your current query:

  - which refers to the previous Lov as `where person.city = :P1_CITY`

Now your list of values wouldn't contain 25.000 rows, but - hopefully - a **lot** less.